# NSInternalInconsistencyException when loading nib file from framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, nib

I create an iOS framework named TestFramework in swift on Xcode 11, and set its `Mach-O Type` to `static library` in the target build settings.

I add a xib file named `MyViewController.xib` with `MyViewController.swift` into the framework project, and made the `MyViewController` class `public`.

Then I create a new iOS app project and add the `TestFramework` into the project as a embed framework.

I use the following code to test the framework.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MyViewController.self)
print("bundle:", bundle)

let vc = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: bundle)
print("ViewController:", vc)
```

I get the result:

```
bundle: NSBundle </Users/xxx/TestApp.app> (loaded)
ViewController: <TestFramework.MyViewController: 0x7fce75403c40>
```

It seems everything's ok.
But when I try to present the viewcontroller, it failed. I got the NSInternalInconsistencyException.

```
self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

The exception detail:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/xxx/TestApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'MyViewController''
```

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the `Bundle(for:)` initializer did not return you the bundle you expected. It looks like it returned you the main bundle. Try to compare the bundle you got from `Bundle(for:)` and `Bundle.main`.

Comment: Oh, I think that the static linking is the problem with the bundle.

Comment: @VladRusu You're right, the `bundle` equals `Bundle.main`. And after I changed the framework back to Dynamic, everything's ok. Thanks. But should I use dynamic since some tutorials told me should use static library instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static framework linking will embed the code in the framework in your application and all classes from the framework will be, in fact, part of the main bundle, in contrast with dynamic libraries.

However, there is a nice way to use resources from a static framework, and that can be achieved by creating a resources bundle which will be linked with the static framework, then load the resources by specifically pointing to that bundle.

1. In you static framework project, create a new bundle
2. Change your bundle base SDK to `Latest iOS` or any platform you wish to support from the bundle's `Build Settings` tab
3. From the project inspector, add the bundle as a target dependency to the static library under the `Build Phases` tab
4. In your test application, after linking the static framework, add your resources bundle to the `Copy Bundle Resources` list from the `Build Phases` tab.

This is it for the setup, now you can use it in the code:

```swift
    guard let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "<your bundle name>" ofType: "bundle"),
          let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath) else { return }
    let viewController = MyViewController(nibName: "<your nib name>" bundle: bundle)
```

You can use this code inside the static framework as well, but you should be always aware that the resources bundle should always be added in the `Copy Bundle Resources` of every app that uses that framework.

In case of dynamic libraries/frameworks, the classes will be loaded with dynamically from their bundle, so accessing the resources is more straightforward.